# how to install php7.2 in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu

how to install php7.2 in Ubuntu 23.04.I try to install php7.2 but it's show the below message:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2'
```

Comment: On LTS versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 22.04), you can install many versions of PHP, including 7.2 using [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) PPA. 23.04 is not an LTS and the PPA does not support it.

Comment: Also, php 7.2 is very old, and is unsupported by even the php foundation https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: The simplest way would be through the use of Docker containers. This will also allow you to have an additional layer of protection for the host in the event the container is being used in a production environment.